# How to execute jar file in php

Tags: php, jar

i read a lot about that, but my problem still remain:

what i'm trying to do is:

```
echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/java -Xmx1g -jar /var/www/html/myDir/ff.jar &");
```

it gives me that error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for code cache
```

i use `nohup` because jar must run even if php terminate.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Shall we assume the command runs just fine from a regular console?

Comment: This post may be of use http://stackoverflow.com/a/1059368/1710831

Comment: from terminal it starts good..

Comment: No way.. it doesn't work even if i add -Xms1g ... any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SELinux enabled on the machine it's running on?  See http://archimedeseureka.blogspot.com/2011/01/executing-java-from-php-in-rhelcentos.html - I had this trouble on a Fedora 18 system and setting httpd_execmem seems to have fixed it.