# Error while creating web service using apache CXF wizard

Tags: cxf

I am creating a web service through the apache CXF. but while i proceed(before the wsdl gets created), i receive the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/tools/java2wsdl/JavaToWSDL

This seems like the java2ws.bat file has some error.
The statement in the bat file is 
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CXF_HOME%\lib\endorsed" -cp "%CXF_JAR%;%TOOLS_JAR%;%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CXF_HOME%\etc\logging.properties" org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS %*

It seems like at Run time,jvm is not able to find the CXF.jar.I added it in the classpath but still the same error
please help me to solve the issue

Comment: A strange thing happened...I just switched my workspace to a new one and it started working

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises while creating JVM. You can refer : [Java Refuses to Start - Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058471/java-refuses-to-start-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

It solved my problem.