# CentOS 5 Installing Java error

Tags: java, installation, centos

I have tried to isntall Java on my linux platform.
I used this:

```
su -c "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk"
```

from http://openjdk.java.net/install/

Later i tried this:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-src.i386
```

But the problem is that i keep getting this when i try to run a .jar file:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit
```

What's the problem?
It's a 32-bit system

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058471/java-refuses-to-start-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap

Answer (score 1):

Your VPS hosting has to low memory.

To launch the JVM need a lot more memory, than just running. Under 512mb ram will have this problems. Buy higher memory hosting plan. Ad this is not a programming question it should be moved to somewhere else section.