# java hotspot(TM) client vm warning:ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m;support was removed

Tags: wso2

When I am running the wso2-DAS product, it shows error as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJq9T.jpg) and I have no idea about how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure you have 2GB memory free in your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ignore the warning. It just says java 8 will ignore `MaxPermSize` option. It's not a problem.

For the 2nd problem, if you have 2GB free memory in your RAM, you can have a look at [Java Refuses to Start - Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058471/java-refuses-to-start-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)