# What is the largest possible heap size with a 64-bit JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, 64-bit, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

The theoretical maximum heap value that can be set with `-Xmx` in a 32-bit system is of course `2^32` bytes, but typically (see: [Understanding max JVM heap size - 32bit vs 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457514/understanding-max-jvm-heap-size-32bit-vs-64bit)) one cannot use all 4GB.

For a 64-bit JVM running in a 64-bit OS on a 64-bit machine, is there any limit besides the theoretical limit of `2^64` bytes or 16 exabytes?

I know that for various reasons (mostly garbage collection), excessively large heaps might not be *wise*, but in light of reading about servers with terrabytes of RAM, I'm wondering what is *possible*.

Comment: I guess you don't have to worry about this limitation for a few years.

Comment: Adding more memory actually *helps* the GC because it is forced to run less often.

Comment: The worst case Full GC time is usually proportional to the size of the heap used. A rough approximation is 1 second per GB.  A full GC of minutes will be unacceptible for most applications.

Comment: With v1.9 of the JVM coming out, the more server-friendly G1 garbage collector [will now](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/248) be the default. As I understand it, this means that there will be more frequent, but much shorter, partial GC sweeps.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use 32-bit references, your heap is limited to 32 GB.

However, if you are willing to use 64-bit references, the size is likely to be limited by your OS, just as it is with 32-bit JVM. e.g. on Windows 32-bit this is 1.2 to 1.5 GB.

Note: you will want your JVM heap to fit into main memory, ideally inside one NUMA region.  That's about 1 TB on the bigger machines.  If your JVM spans NUMA regions the memory access and the GC in particular will take much longer. If your JVM heap start swapping it might take hours to GC, or even make your machine unusable as it thrashes the swap drive.

Note: You can access large direct memory and memory mapped sizes even if you use 32-bit references in your heap. i.e. use well above 32 GB.

[Compressed oops in the Hotspot JVM](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops)

> Compressed oops represent managed pointers (in many but not all places in the JVM) as 32-bit values which must be scaled by a factor of 8 and added to a 64-bit base address to find the object they refer to. This allows applications to address up to four billion objects (not bytes), or a heap size of up to about 32Gb. At the same time, data structure compactness is competitive with ILP32 mode.

Comment: 32 bit references can only address up to 4 GB, don't they? How would you go about configuring 64 bit references?

Comment: @Peter 32 bit ram size is 4GB. So i think u got the info about heap size wrong for that case.

Comment: With a 64-bit JVM, the latest versions have `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` on by default.  What this does is use 32-bit "compressed" references to objects.  Since objects are 8-byte aligned (and their addresses' lowest 3 bits are always 0), it can reference 2^32 * 8 bytes or 32 GB.

Comment: @Peter I disagree. Line from IBM "WebSphere Commerce works in 32-bit mode. 
Although the maximum theoretical heap limit for the 32-bit JVM is 4GB, due to various constraints and reserved memory areas, in practice the limits are much lower". From [ibm link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.igaa%2F_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html)

Comment: Thats for a 32-bit JVM as it states. On a 64-bit JVM, the limit for 32-bit references is 32 GB. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html `-XX:+UseCompressedOops  Enables the use of compressed pointers (object references represented as 32 bit offsets instead of 64-bit pointers) for optimized 64-bit performance with Java heap sizes less than 32gb.`

Comment: I dont think UseCompressedOops say about using 8bit pointers. The reason how i knew that IBM had the details was, i attended a seminar from IBM and they gave these details. They also have the same UseCompressedOops parameter, and its use as explained from IBM presenter was for using 32bit pointers in most cases so that the memory management used 32bit and save heap space instead of using 64bit pointers when possible. I will try to find that presentation for you.

Comment: This links from oracle shows exactly what it does with the machine code it generates demonstrating the address is shifted by 3 bits. http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops

Comment: Doesn't this answer miss the point of the qustion? It asks *maximum possible* for 64bit, while this mostly focuses on compressed oops and 32bit, neither of which relates to the maximum.

Comment: I think you'd better mention that the assumption is on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @the8472 I would read the second sentence again. A 64-bit JVM is limited by the OS it runs on, a limit which is likely to change over time.

Answer (score 3):

The answer clearly depends on the JVM implementation. [Azul claim](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zing/whatisit) that their JVM

> can scale ... to more than a 1/2 Terabyte of memory

By "can scale" they appear to mean "runs wells", as opposed to "runs at all".

Answer (score 2):

Windows imposes a memory limit per process, you can see what it is for each version [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#memory_limits)

See:

`User-mode virtual address space for each 64-bit process;
With IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set (default):
x64:  8 TB
Intel IPF:  7 TB
2 GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE cleared`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `-Xmx32255M` is accepted by vmargs for compressed oops.

Comment: All values are accepted silently. The question is if they are obeyed by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

> For a 64-bit JVM running in a 64-bit OS on a 64-bit machine, is there any limit besides the theoretical limit of 2^64 bytes or 16 exabytes?

You also have to take hardware limits into account. While pointers may be 64bit current CPUs can only address a [less than 2^64 bytes worth of virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#VIRTUAL-ADDRESS-SPACE).

With uncompressed pointers the hotspot JVM needs a continuous chunk of virtual address space for its heap. So the second hurdle after hardware is the operating system providing such a large chunk, not all OSes support this.

And the third one is practicality. Even if you can have that much virtual memory it does not mean the CPUs support that much physical memory, and without physical memory you will end up swapping, which will adversely affect the performance of the JVM because the GCs generally have to touch a large fraction of the heap.

As other answers mention compressed oops: By bumping the object alignment higher than 8 bytes the limits with compressed oops can be [increased beyond 32GB](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040176)

Answer (score -3):

In theory everything is possible but reality you find the numbers much lower than you might expect.
I have been trying to address huge spaces on servers often and found that even though a server can have huge amounts of memory it surprised me that most software actually never can address it in real scenario's simply because the cpu's are not fast enough to really address them.
Why would you say right ?! . Timings thats the endless downfall of every enormous machine which i have worked on.
So i would advise to not go overboard by addressing huge amounts just because you can, but use what you think could be used.
Actual values are often much lower than what you expected.
Ofcourse non of us really uses hp 9000 systems at home and most of you actually ever will go near the capacity of your home system ever. 
For instance most users do not have more than 16 Gb of memory in their system. Ofcourse some of the casual gamers use work stations for a game once a month but i bet that is a very small percentage. 
So coming down to earth means i would address on a 8 Gb 64 bit system not much more than 512 mb for heapspace or if you go overboard try 1 Gb. I am pretty sure its even with these numbers pure overkill.
I have constant monitored the memory usage during gaming to see if the addressing would make any difference but did not notice any difference at all when i addressed much lower values or larger ones. Even on the server/workstations there was no visible change in performance no matter how large i set the values.
That does not say some jave users might be able to make use of more space addressed, but this far i have not seen any of the applications needing so much ever.
Ofcourse i assume that their would be a small difference in performance if java instances would run out of enough heapspace to work with.
This far i have not found any of it at all, however lack of real installed memory showed instant drops of performance if you set too much heapspace.
When you have a 4 Gb system you run quickly out of heapspace and then you will see some errors and slowdowns because people address too much space which actually is not free in the system so the os starts to address drive space to make up for the shortage hence it starts to swap.