# What will be the default heap size if i have 4 GB RAM machine with 64 bit JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I have desktop machine with 4 GB RAM. By default how much memory is reserved for heap?

Comment: Go through this link it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663174/what-is-the-largest-possible-heap-size-with-a-64-bit-jvm

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: `System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());` Try it yourself. :)