# how to do JBOSS 6 EAP profiling using jprofiler?

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss7.x, profiler, jprofiler

We are trying to do profiling for our app which is running on JBOSS 6 EAP using jprofiler. However, when running standalone_jprofiler.bat gives error,

```
    JProfiler> Protocol version 36
    JProfiler> Using JVMTI
    JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
    JProfiler> 32-bit library
    JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
    JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    Could not reserve enough space for object heap
    JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
    JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
    JProfiler> Native library initialized
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

We have tried to increase memory in standalone.conf.bat file as

```
    set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
```

The below statement is appended by jprofiler in the bat file,

```
    set JAVA_OPTS=-agentpath:E:\ProgramFiles\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849  -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl %JAVA_OPTS%
```

I am not sure whether jprofiler7 supports JBOSS 6 EAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

indicates that the heap size is too big. If you load an agent library, the 32-bit space is fragmented, see

[Understanding max JVM heap size - 32bit vs 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457514/understanding-max-jvm-heap-size-32bit-vs-64bit)

Try lowering the heap size to 1G or lower.