# Maximum heap size for JVM on a 32-bit and 64-bit windows server

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory, 32bit-64bit

I have a third party application that was installed on my Windows Server 2008 and came with a JRE.

The server is a 64-bit machine, but when I try to adjust the heap size past about 1.5 GB, the JVM errors out.

I have found this article: [Understanding max JVM heap size - 32bit vs 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457514/understanding-max-jvm-heap-size-32bit-vs-64bit)

So if it's 32-bit windows, the max size is about 1.5gb to 2gb since windows takes some in the middle and needs to be continuous. So shouldn't the 64-bit be a lot more?

Comment: Is he JVM a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM? (run `java -version` to know)

Comment: yeah how do you test what came with the third party app? or maybe someone installed the jvm before. how do i test that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the jvm with -d64 option ? I think I have read somewhere at a point that some VMs run in 32 bit mode by default