# How Much Memory Can I Allocate?

Tags: java, memory, ram

If I have 16 GB of RAM on my machine, how much can I allocate to a java command line program I'm executing? I assume `java -Xmx 16g...` will crash my system?

**EDIT:**
In light of the comments, I tried `java -Xmx16g...`, and it did not crash my machine. The program still ran out of memory. I tried `java -Xmx32g...`, which did crash my machine.

From the comments below (which have been really enlightening), I guess I just need to keep playing around with the allocations.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Try it and see. OS's provide [swap space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) that make the total amount of virtual memory available larger than the amount of physical memory present, as long as not all the memory is needed simultaneously (pages can be "swapped out").

Comment: @RC : why not? do you still believe 640kB is enough?

Comment: @RC. - I know it was kind of overkill. But I do huge data processing, and don't always have access to my school's servers. EDIT: I was saving up for over a year, and since Apple kept delaying the release date of the 2013 MBP, I just kept saving more... :-)

Comment: @njzk2 Hey, I used to program an Apple II+ with 56KB of RAM!  I also used to walk five miles to school, uphill both ways ...

Comment: @njzk2 no but 16g is some serious RAM usage IMHO

Comment: This link about [maximum heap size](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html) can be useful for you. It depends on your OS.

Comment: Here is your answer:
[Link to Stack Overflow Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457514/understanding-max-jvm-heap-size-32bit-vs-64bit

Answer (score 8):

The size the heap memory of the virtual machine is controlled by the options **- Xms**
and **- Xmx** .

The first specifies the initial heap size and the second maximum size.

The allocation is done within the **JVM itself** ,and not on the **OS**. As more memory is needed, the JVM allocates a block of memory until the Xmx is reached.

**If you need more than that, an OutOfMemoryError is thrown.**

It is common to use the same value for **Xms** and **Xmx**,
causing the VM to allocate memory in the operating system only at the beginning of an execution,
not depending on the **OS specific behavior**.

---

***In your case, since you set 32g as your Xmx and your system crashed, it seems you don't have this memory (swap + memory ram)***

If you manually change the **virtual memory size** of your system, the configuration will work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for your OS to allocate more than 16GB and therefore your system crash. Apart from XMX and XMS that is stated in another answer there is also an  -XX:+AggressiveHeap option which inspects the machine resources (size of memory and number of processors) and attempts to set various parameters to be optimal for long-running, memory allocation-intensive jobs