# java.io.IOException: exception - While restoring DB in Sql Developer 4.1

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-backups

I am facing a problem while restoring  database of size 8.14GB  in Sql developer4.1 in Oracle 11g r2. It's giving error of java.io.IOException.
like this-

```
java.io.IOException: exception loading F:\PROJECTS\NJ_State_iCare\ICARE_BACKUP.sql
at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.openImpl(TextNode.java:549)
at oracle.ide.model.Node.open(Node.java:1045)
at oracle.ide.model.Node.open(Node.java:992)
at oracle.ide.model.Node.ensureOpen(Node.java:2417)
at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.acquireTextBuffer(TextNode.java:767)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.WorksheetGUI.<init>(WorksheetGUI.java:818)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.createGUI(Worksheet.java:1027)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.getWorksheetGUI(Worksheet.java:1376)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.getGUI(Worksheet.java:1190)
at oracle.ide.editor.Editor.getDefaultFocusComponent(Editor.java:233)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.getDefaultFocusComponent(Worksheet.java:1151)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.open(Worksheet.java:1473)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.EditorState.openEditor(EditorState.java:318)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.SplitPane.doLayout(SplitPane.java:580)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.whenCurrentEditorChanges(NbEditorManager.java:1591)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.whenCurrentEditorChanges(TabGroup.java:1026)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.setCurrentTabGroupState(TabGroup.java:847)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.addTabGroupState(TabGroup.java:129)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:546)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:523)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.openEditor(NbEditorManager.java:391)
at oracle.ide.cmd.OpenCommand.openWithNoProject(OpenCommand.java:337)
at oracle.ide.cmd.OpenCommand.access$100(OpenCommand.java:62)
at oracle.ide.cmd.OpenCommand$1.run(OpenCommand.java:266)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at oracle.javatools.buffer.VectorBuffers.addBuffer(VectorBuffers.java:96)
at oracle.javatools.buffer.EOLNormalizer.process(EOLNormalizer.java:157)
at oracle.javatools.buffer.EOLNormalizer$ReaderNormalizer.normalizeData(EOLNormalizer.java:307)
at oracle.javatools.buffer.AbstractTextBuffer.read(AbstractTextBuffer.java:1406)
at oracle.javatools.buffer.AbstractTextBuffer.read(AbstractTextBuffer.java:1350)
at oracle.javatools.buffer.TextBufferDecorator.read(TextBufferDecorator.java:468)
at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.loadTextBuffer(TextNode.java:307)
at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.openImpl(TextNode.java:537)
at oracle.ide.model.Node.open(Node.java:1045)
at oracle.ide.model.Node.open(Node.java:992)
at oracle.ide.model.Node.ensureOpen(Node.java:2417)
at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.acquireTextBuffer(TextNode.java:767)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.WorksheetGUI.<init>(WorksheetGUI.java:818)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.createGUI(Worksheet.java:1027)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.getWorksheetGUI(Worksheet.java:1376)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.getGUI(Worksheet.java:1190)
at oracle.ide.editor.Editor.getDefaultFocusComponent(Editor.java:233)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.getDefaultFocusComponent(Worksheet.java:1151)
at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet.open(Worksheet.java:1473)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.EditorState.openEditor(EditorState.java:318)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.SplitPane.doLayout(SplitPane.java:580)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.whenCurrentEditorChanges(NbEditorManager.java:1591)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.whenCurrentEditorChanges(TabGroup.java:1026)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.setCurrentTabGroupState(TabGroup.java:847)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.editor.TabGroup.addTabGroupState(TabGroup.java:129)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:546)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.createEditor(NbEditorManager.java:523)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorManager.openEditor(NbEditorManager.java:391)
at oracle.ide.cmd.OpenCommand.openWithNoProject(OpenCommand.java:337)
at oracle.ide.cmd.OpenCommand.access$100(OpenCommand.java:62)
at oracle.ide.cmd.OpenCommand$1.run(OpenCommand.java:266)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
```

Not getting the root of the problem. If anyone can guess please suggest.

Comment: Did you spot the "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error in the log? (And there isn't a 4.1 yet, do you mean 4.0.1, and did you check if the same thing happens in the current 4.0.2?)

Comment: @AlexPoole yes have also checked with 4.0.2                           It is giving 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: And yes i mean 4.0.1 By mistake i wrote 4.1

Answer (score 1):

By default SQL Developer's heap size seems to be 810942464 bytes (Help->About->Properties), though it's specified at 800M.

You can change that by shutting down SQL Developer and editing the configuration file; on Windows that is:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf
```

At the bottom you'll see a setting like:

```
AddVMOption -Xmx800m
```

Change that to a higher value, e.g.:

```
AddVMOption -Xmx1024m
```

... restart SQL Developer, check the value in About (mine now says 1037959168 bytes). You might need more than that though, this is just an example. The maximum value you can use is restricted by the platform you're on though, and [this may be of interest if your JVM won't start with larger values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2457514/266304). At some point you may just be trying to do something that your machine can't handle.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1 having 4GB ram and 500GB hard disk and 64bit processor. Isn't it enough space. I have increased this size upto  2048m  But still not working.

Comment: You might want to [ask about this on the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)) then, to see if there's a workaround.

Comment: @Yogi - the flag sets the maximum size, so heap size.max; the used size will start off smallish and then vary depending on what you're doing, but can't exceed the max value.