# IntelliJ random "Could not start Java Virtual machine"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Every once in a while, IntelliJ will refuse to compile my project with the exact same settings that used to work fine.

I have a huge project and normally use a heap size of 2000MB for the compiler with a 64bit JDK.
With a lower heap size, it takes hours to compile this project.

I'm on windows and also tried to compile after a fresh reboot but to no avail.

Anyone who has a clue where to start looking to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

JVM needs a contiguous area of memory to operate (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028259/579828)). Your memory is fragmented and the OS can't always provide that. If you work on Windows increasing the paging file size may help.

Comment: Is there anything I can do about this? I have enough free memory so the OS should not be swapping to disk...