# download the JRockit 5 jre

Tags: java, jvm, jrockit

I want to download Bea JRockIt 5 because the JRE doesn’t seem to be able to allocate VM more than 1.6 GB.
please i not find the link for download the JRockIT jre 
I use machine 32 bits windows7 and ram 3GB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you current jvm can't allocate more than ~1.6G, no other one will (you might get a few 10-100MB more, but not much more). This is a limitation of your operating system.

Answer (score 4):

The bottom line is that the limit you are seeing is not actually a JVM imposed limit.  So changing to JRockit is not going to help.

Most 32-bit Windows operating systems limit the virtual memory for a user application (such as a JVM) to 2Gb.  However, there is a boot switch for Windows Server 2003 that enables applications up to 3Gb ... on hardware that supports PAE : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487508.aspx.

Your alternatives are:

- If you are running Windows Server 2003 - do what the link says.
- Switch to 32 bit Linux or 32 bit Solaris.  Both allow more than 2Gb for user applications.
- Switch to a 64 bit operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why a simple Google search didn't suffice, but this is [clearly available on OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/downloads/index.html).

As far as allocation of memory for the JVM is concerned, it is unlikely that you will be able to get any amount more than 2GB. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080023/jvm-heapsize-on-32-bit-os) and the most voted answer.