# Why does the Java VM update 25 crash with internal error

Tags: java, crash, jvm

Since Java update 25 the VM crashes occasionally with internal error. With previous versions <25 it was working fine. According to the release notes, the hotspot compiler was modified in update 25. Does it produce defect code that causes the crash? It does not crash if the JIT compiler is turned off with -Xint. I filed a bug here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7054478 .

How do I interpret the log file to find out where the crash occurs. I am not able to identify the lines in my Java code where it happenes.

Comment: Try playing with `-client` and `-server`.  The two Hotspots are different.

Comment: are you using any native code?

Comment: Post the crash log. It might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344546/java-6-update-25-vm-crash-insufficient-memory

Comment: The link to the bug report is broken, which makes this Question next to useless.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that an internal assertion failed - the JVM was not in the state it expected to be.  This is a good thing because it avoids propagating errors, but a bad thing because it doesn't tell you how to get around it.

If simple tricks like -client or -server doesn't help, then consider a different JVM.

- IBM has a Windows JVM, but it is a bit tricky to get.  The easiest for now would be a development package http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/index.html
- Oracle also have JRockit. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/index.html

This will allow you to work while Oracle has a look at your bug.  It is low priority though, so it make take a while.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea to use another VM, I will check it.

Comment: Well, the actual problem is not solved, but using when using JRockit the issue disappeared and in Oracles current Java 1.7.0_25 (actually already in some previous version) it seems to be fixed. The reason for the issue was some VM internal bug, I at least think it was that, and it seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I searched the Bug Database for the string "Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter", and there were three other hits.  They all seem to be about unexpected exceptions in native code propagating back across the JNI boundary.

Is that clue relevant to your application?