# SQL stored procedure to Matlab datatransfer - out of memory

Tags: sql, matlab, fetch, data-transfer

I have a stored procedure on SQLserver that is executed by Matlab.  The procedure returns some `1.5million` rows.  My OS is XP x32 and Matlab version is 2011a 32-bit.  Whenever I try to fetch this data, I get a Java Heap Memory Size error.  I tried using rowLimit as 200000 but I still got the same error.  Interestingly, SQL data is easily transferred when the stored procedure returns <700000 rows.  (if you want to know, there are 15 cols).

```
clear all                                      % free all available memory
conn = database('xxx' , 'userid', 'passwrd') ; % works fine
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','numeric');      % works fine
curs = exec(conn,'execute xxxxxx') ;           % works fine
fetch(curs) OR fetch(curs,200000) ;     --> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Can you suggest a way to import such data sets?  Thanks!

Comment: What are the column types of the result set coming back?

Comment: double in Matlab, mostly float in SQL. Cols with chars in them become NaNs.

Comment: What DBMS are you connecting to (e.g. Oracle/MS SQL Server/etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to increase the *heap size* of the JVM. Refer to this article on how to do it
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18I2C/index.html

Regarding the actual size to set, refer to this thread:
[Java maximum memory on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp)