# JMeter not working after increasing the heap size beyond 1577 Mb

Tags: jvm

When I tried to increase the JVM heap size to to 2048 Mb, it throws an exception while initializing the JVM. I have tried it on both 32-bit & 64-bit OS but was able to get the solution. Also, please tell me if installing the 64-bit JVM or JRE will solve the problem or not. 
Can someone also let me know, how to find which version of JRE I'm currently running?

Answer (score 0):

The memory limit is here: [Java maximum memory on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp)

The version is `java -version`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I got the solution. It is actually the problem with the allocated memory space. As in case with 32-bit JRE, it cannot allocate memory beyond that address space on even 64-bit OS. Thus, to use memory or allocate memory beyond that address we should use 64-bit JRE. This is only when we use any java application but when we need to develop any Java application then we should use 64-bit JDK in that case.