# Unable to increase MyEclipse heap memory ( Xmx)

Tags: java, heap-memory, myeclipse

I have MyEclipse version 8.5.

I increased heap memory by changing the value of parameter -Xmx from 1024m to 2048m in the file .../MyEclipse/myeclipse.ini file and restarted MyEclipse, a large dialog box appears and MyEclipse does not start.

When I bring it back to 1024m, it starts working.[image: This is the error received once MyEclipse is restarted]

How can I increase the heap size to avoid out of memory exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on a 32 bit machine, ~1400Mb is your memory limit. 2048mb is too high.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why 1400Mb on 32 bit machine?

Comment: "Java maximum memory on Windows XP" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 32bit Windows, the maximum memory you can have is about 1.5g. Try with -Xmx1280m.