# Galaxy s3 emulator

Tags: android, galaxy

Starting emulator for AVD 's3'

```
Failed to allocate memory: 8 T
his application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I am getting this problem while running s3 emulator with this configuration

```
Target: Google APIs - API Level 15 Skin: Built-in WXGA720

Hardware Back/Home: yes
Abstracted LCD density: 320
Keyboard lid support: no
Max VM application heap size: 48
Device ram size: 512
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a common problem when setting up the AVD that you have to manually edit the config file to fix. On my WinXP comp this is located at

`C:\Documents and Settings\username\.android\avd\name_of_avd.avd\config.ini`

Change the memory settings from `hw.ramSize=512` to `hw.ramSize=512MB`

Save the file and reopen the avd. This worked for me except I use `hw.ramSize=1024MB`

Answer (score 0):

Set the resolution manually to 720x1280 instead of using predefined WXGA720.