# How can I allocate more than 1024 MB RAM on AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, ram

I want to work with 1024MB or greater RAM sizes, but when I try to start my Virtual Device, I receive this error:

```
Failed to allocate memory: 8
```

After research, some solutions which did not work for me are:

- Manually change avd's .ini files etc.
- Run emulator as Administrator
- Run from command line
- [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853541/why-cant-i-boot-an-avd-from-eclipse-with-1024-mb-of-ram/14487341#14487341)
- [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory/6884186#6884186)

System specifications:

- 64bit Windows 7 64Bit
- i7 3610QM CPU
- 8GB RAM
- 2GB Graphic card

Am using Android **4.2**

Comment: Please refer to this li[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853541/why-cant-i-boot-an-avd-from-eclipse-with-1024-mb-of-ram

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to change you Emulator - if its Version is 20.

Here is a link that describes the problem: [Emulator stops working after upgrading to version 20](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33930)

*Update*

I have found also this link: [Android Virtual Device (AVD) Emulator stopped working](http://droidsquad.blogspot.de/2011/04/android-virtual-device-avd-stopped.html) - its interesting, that in comments one user post follows: *"Thought you might be interested to know, on my system I have 8gb of RAM, yet I was unable to set the Device ram size to 2048, but when lowering it to 1024 it worked."*

Maybe the RAM managemetn is generally the problem for some Android SDK.