# Eclipse Juno with JRE 7 causes problems on startup

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jvm-arguments, javaw

The issue that is explained seems to be a common one and different solutions have been proposed already, many of which work. [One example of this discussion can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine).

My question is more about *why* rather than *how*.

We have been wrestling with this issue here ourselves as well and found that if we launch eclipse using javaw.exe the problem occurs, but if we invoke Eclipse using jvm.dll the problem does not appear. Even though in both cases the `eclipse.ini` remained same.

To explain my case I will use the example of launching `eclipse.exe` from command line with a single `-vm` argument. For reference below is the `eclipse.ini` that we are using:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dderby.stream.error.field=java.lang.System.err
```

You can see that the memory requested for allocation is quite a lot for both heap (1280m) and PermGen (512m). If you are unable to reproduce the issue you can try increasing the memory until the error occurs.

There are three different command lines that you may use:

```
eclipse.exe -vm ..\jre\bin\javaw.exe
eclipse.exe -vm ..\jre\bin
eclipse.exe -vm ..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

Only the *first* one causes the error (javaw.exe). The remaining two options launch eclipse successfully. Reducing memory requirement in eclipse.ini also fixes the problem obviously.

So my question is, why does javaw.exe fail when the other two command lines work? What is the difference between choosing these different paths? Does one enforce parameters more strictly than the others?

Environment: Eclipse: 3.8-win32, JRE: 7u7-win32, Windows 7 x64

Comment: Do you have more then 1 Java Version ?

Comment: Do you really need to give it that much RAM?  I work on some pretty good sized projects and I've never had to bump up the JVM RAM for Eclipse (I'm also running Juno on JRE7)...

Comment: @KevinEsche yes but I am assuming that it shouldn't be a factor because I am providing the vm path myself.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch, the problem is not really whether I need this much RAM, this problem sometimes even occurs on low requirements as well, it depends on applications already running on the system and available memory. My purpose is to find out why this happens and why does some of the things (as described in the question) solve this problem. Like using a different command line or reducing memory requirements.

Comment: for what is worth, juno borked on my pc I endede up switchign to intellij - well worth the admission price

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why pointing Eclipse to the executable fails but the dll does not, but I can offer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9304270/639520) to explain the problem. The gist of it is that on Windows, the JVM needs to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory for your heap, and if it can't then it fails to start.

Perhaps [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Finding_a_VM.2C_Using_JNI_Invocation_or_Executing_Java) will help figure out why pointing to the dll seems to work. Otherwise, I'd ask on the [Eclipse Equinox forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/31/).

Comment: Thanks for links, they were informative. This at least explains why the 2nd and 3rd command-lines in the question above are equivalent. The DLL is always preferred. `On most platforms, we use JNI launching unless a -vm argument was given that points directly to a java executable.`

Comment: Invoking javaw.exe starts a new process for the JVM, so perhaps it is in a better position to enforce requirements such as a contiguous memory block. On the other hand, invoking the DLL causes the JVM to be instantiated in the current process and perhaps at this point the JVM cannot really entertain the -Xmx and -Xms attributes as the process is already created. So loading the DLL just causes the memory attributes to be ignored and hence the checks. Could this be a valid explanation?