# Can't add memory of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

My machine has more than 3G free memory. But when I set Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize to about 800M in eclipse.ini, I can't open eclipse, with an error "failed to create the Java Vitual Machine" .
Anyone ever meet this problem?

Comment: And without the parameter it does work?

Comment: @Jerodev yes. When I set them to less than 800M. it works

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit or a 64-bit operating system on your computer?

Comment: @Jerodev It's a 64-bit Win8, and 32-bit jdk1.7

Comment: You should try installing the 64-bit jdk version

Comment: What's the specific error you get? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for

Comment: Can you add your eclipse.ini file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the 32-bit version of Eclipse. Try to run the 64-bit one. You can find your version in `eclipse.ini`: look for `x86_64` string(usually on fourth line). The only `x86` means you have 32-bit installation. 
Also don't forget install 64-bit Java.

Comment: If you run 64 bit Eclipse you must also run a 64 bit JVM

Comment: @greg-449 i concur with you.