# No Java Virtual machine was found

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have a 8Gb of ram and I have a java version 1.8.0_111 (I added it in Environment Variables->System).
I downloaded a scala IDE for Eclipse `scala-SDK-4.5.0-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64`, I can't install it, it shown an error this following:

```
A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following location:
E:\Download\scala-SDK-4.5.0-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw;exe in your current PATH
```

Knowing that I followed this answer of @Mohamed Adel:

[“Error occurred during initialization of VM; Could not reserve enough space for object heap” using -Xmx3G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for)

Can you tell me where is the error in my steps ?

Comment: The path displayed seems even syntactically wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Kayaman it worked fine and it resolved.