# Pycharm (Error occurred during initialization of VM)

Tags: pycharm

I ran into an error when trying to start Pycharm in Centos.

> Error occurred during initialization of VM 
>   Could not reserve enough space for 10240000KB object heap

It seems there is problem with Java. 
The directory I am running Pycharm has a space of 4.4T .
I followed related posts but still no success.
For example,

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205969324-PyCharm-doesn-t-start-Says-initial-heap-size-larger-then-maximal-heap-size

[Intellij occasionally unable to reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885926/intellij-occasionally-unable-to-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

[Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean 4.4 TB? Also how much is available space in directory where 'java' is installed already ?

Comment: @Obaid Ur Rehman, Yes I mean 4.4 TB. the space of /usr/bin/ where java resides is 7.1G. I also reinstalled java in my local directory with a lot of space but it fails with the same error.

Comment: Yes I think admin may have changed directories or installed new packages. However try to free space up to 10 G in directory /usr/bin.