# "Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap"

Tags: java, android, jvm

Whenever I started Android studio to begin a project it's showing

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for 1048576KB object heap.

I've searched through without any tangible solution.

I'm wondering what could have gone wrong.

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this too ? :

"Here is how to fix it: Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced(tab)->Environment Variables->System

Variables->New:
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M

Variable name: Path
Variable value: ;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;F:\JDK\bin;
Change this to your appropriate path."

There are a few other solutions here:
[“Error occurred during initialization of VM; Could not reserve enough space for object heap” using -Xmx3G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for)

Comment: The second variable you provided is  inexistent in my Java folder.

Comment: not working for gradlew wrapper in intellij idea 2019.1.1 (ultimate edition.)