# "Could not reserve enough space for object heap" during Oracle 12c installation

Tags: oracle, oracleclient, oracle18c

I want to upgrade my Oracle client from 12c to 18c, but there is an issue.

I deinstall Oracle 12c and delete everything from that. Now I want to install Oracle client 18c and it doesn't work.

The command line says:

> "Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for 1048576KB object heap"

I don't know what I can do to solve this problem.
Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please refer: [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for)

Comment: Another [Stack Overflow answer to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this looking for the correct method on Oracle DB, Oracle EM, or most any Oracle product installed by the Oracle Universal Installer (OUI)... it is as follows: Edit the Java memory parameters in the oraparams.ini file. This file has various locations depending on the exact software and version being installed.

However, in my own instance, trying to install via Chef Workstation's `knife bootstrap` feature on Windows, this editing doesn't work. The JVM heap still fails to initialize.