# Why I am getting a JVM max heap space error?

Tags: java, exception, jvm, heap-memory

I am trying to run a certain java program with more than 1024M heap space. Even though I have 4GB of RAM and a 32bit OS, its saying that the max is 1024M. Below is the batch code I am trying to use to start the program:

```
@echo off
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar program.jar
```

Could someone explain why I am getting a JVM "could not reserve enough space" error?

Comment: Not sure what OS you're running, but on Windows XP I was only able to allocate 1200-1400 MB. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205

Comment: On a 64-bit JVM you can make the heap size anything, but a practical limit is usually of the order of 100 GB (as the length of the full GC is proportional heap sixe)

Comment: I am using a Windows 7 32bit OS with a total of 4GB of DDR3 RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You're on Windows, and the max address space a single 32 bit program can have is 2GB.
Now since the process and system needs some of that for housekeeping stuff (e.g. .dlls) , you can't use all those 2GB for the java heap. So try with less, e.g. 1.5 GB.

You can make 32 bit programs get 3GB of address space through a boot switch, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291988) , which can be an alternative to switching to a 64 bit OS if you really need more heap space.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the "could not reserve enough space" error because there must be no contiguous block of memory available in your RAM of size 2048M. I would suggest that you either reduce the -Xms to 512M since I don't think initially you will require 2048M heap space. If this doesnt work, then you will need to reduce the -Xmx value.