# Simultaneously run Java Virtual Machines

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, jvm-arguments, jvm-crash

I am trying to run some different Eclipse RCP implementations simultaneously, and I receive the following error message: "Java was started but returned exit code=1".

I understand that happens when a xmx or xms parameter greater than between 1.2 and 1.8 GB is set (this quantity depends on the machine). But my problem is not only how big is this parameter for a single machine, I don't always receive this error message when I am trying to execute more than one virtual machine at the same time, I don't know which conditions are evaluated by the java virtual machine in order to launch this error message.

Do you know how could I see which conditions are evaluated from the Java VMs in order to launch this error message? This way I could establish the right xmx and xms parameters.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM needs a continuous memory space to have its Object Heap allocated.

Trying to have more than one JVM in execution at a time, makes quite more difficult to find such a memory block. Even by having free GBs of memory.

I found the answer here:

[Tools to view/solve Windows XP memory fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103622/tools-to-view-solve-windows-xp-memory-fragmentation)