# Dynamic 2D Array allocation in C

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array

How I should allocate dynamic arrays in C? Currently I have a function I wrote called `malloc2D` that looks like this:

```
void* malloc2D(size_t unitSize, uint firstCount, uint secondCount)
{
    void** pointer = malloc(sizeof(id) * firstCount);
    for (int i =0; i < firstCount; i ++){
        pointer[i] = malloc(unitSize * secondCount);
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

It works fine however I have been told that it puts a lot of strain on the memory allocating separately. What is the best or most conventional way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allocate the array as a contiguous bloc like this. Suppose you want ints:

```
int (*arr)[secondCount] = malloc( sizeof(int[firstCount][secondCount]) );
```

You could hide this behind a macro which takes the typename as a macro argument, although the code is simple enough that that is not really necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You could allocate the entire block at once:

```
int ** foo;

foo = malloc(sizeof(int*) * firstCount);
foo[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * firstCount * secondCount);
for (int i=1; i<firstCount; i++)
{
    foo[i] = foo[0] + i * secondCount;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to keep what you have.

1. It's already developed.
2. It's tested.
3. It's intuitive/readable without using a macro.
4. It's extensible.
5. No bottleneck has quantitatively been identified.

Sometimes trying to optimize when there is not a problem can hurt performance.  Have you done any benchmarks against your friends theory?

`malloc`ing a big chunk requires locating contiguous address space, and might even cause `malloc` to fail when your current method would succeed ([address space fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684004/heap-fragmentation-and-windows-memory-manager), etc).

When I said your current implementation is extensible, I mean it is trivial to resize.  Should you allocate for a [100][3] and later realize you need a [100][4] then all you need to do is 100 **very** small reallocs, likely not changing addresses.  However, should the macro method need resizing, you need to `realloc` the whole chunk which may not exist contiguously.  Even worse, the data is no longer in the right place to be accessed by the macro because the math has changed, so you will need a series of expensive `memmove`s.

To generalize, I think it is important to always code with readability, maintainability, and ease of use in mind - and only optimize away from that after establishing a bottleneck.

Comment: A problem with the existing code is how to use it. Suppose it's meant to be an array of ints. To be correct the calling code would be something like `void **arr = malloc2D(sizeof(int), N, M); int a = ((int *)arr[x])[y]`.   I have a bad feeling that people might try to write `int **arr = malloc2D(sizeof(int), N, M);` which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Having said that - in an existing large codebase it is probably better to let sleeping dogs lie.