# Initializing an array size using another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I am reading two values from a text file and saving them into an array, lets call it array1. 
Now, is it possible to initialize a 2D array using the elements of arrays1 ?
(i.e. char array2 [array[0]][array[1]]; )

I already tried this and the program started acting weird. I also tried moving the values of the elements in an integer and then use the integer as the array size. This method did not work either.

Any suggestions of how I can implement this please?

Comment: You can initialize arrays to variable sizes in functions because functions allocate the memory on the stack.  However if things are acting weird, there might be a problem with pointers or going out of bounds. Need to see the code. Question is too vague and general

Comment: You haven't shown the faulty code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic 2D array allocation in C family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526301/dynamic-2d-array-allocation-in-c-family)

Comment: It is possible if C99 or later.

Comment: http://ideone.com/9glt6p

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array can be initialized using the array initialization syntax only if second the dimension of the array is known at compile time.

Example:

```
// Create a 1 x 2 array.
char array2[][2] = {{array[0], array[1]}};

// Create a 2 x 2 array.
// Only array2[1][0] and array2[1][0] are initialized
// from array. Rest are zero initialized.
char array2[][2] = {{array[0]}, {array[1]}};

// Create a 3 x 2 array.
// Only array2[0][1] and array2[0][1] are initialized
// from array. Rest are zero initialized.
char array2[3][2] = {{array[0], array[1]}};
```